# PHP simple html dom find after find

Tags: php

How do I execute find loop within find loop ? I keep getting `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object` in line `echo $li->find('span')->innertext;`.

```
// get the html
$html = file_get_html('<url>');

// loop through the required element
foreach($html->find('body') as $body){

    // loop through the selected element
    $lis = $body->find('li');

    foreach($lis as $li){
        // loop through li to get the required span
        echo $li->find('span')->innertext;
    }
}
```

I am using Simple Html Dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: which line generates your error?

Comment: I guess `echo $li->find('span')` returns an array of spans inside `$li`. Use another loop, or `implode`...

Comment: ok so the assumption is `$li->find('span')` doesn't return an object. so don't called `innertext` without first checking the object.

Comment: what do you expect as output?

Comment: I need to execute `foreach` inside `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because the find `span` returns an array or null if the second parameter is used

```
// get the html
$html = file_get_html('<url>');

// loop through the required element
foreach($html->find('body') as $body){

// loop through the selected element
$lis = $body->find('li');

    foreach($lis as $li){
        // loop through li to get the required span
        $span = $li->find('span', 0);
        if(null !== $span){
            echo $span->innertext;
        }
     }
}
```

And I think you may want to check [traverse the dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_traverse_traverse)

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like the following:

```
// get the html
$html = file_get_html('<url>');

// loop through the required element
foreach($html->find('li > span') as $span){

    echo span->innertext;
}
```

Some examples (from site) are given below to clarify your understanding:

```
// Find all <li> in <ul> 
$es = $html->find('ul li');

// Find Nested <div> tags
$es = $html->find('div div div'); 

// Find all <td> in <table> which class=hello 
$es = $html->find('table.hello td');

// Find all td tags with attribite align=center in table tags 
$es = $html->find(''table td[align=center]');
```

You should read the docs for better understanding. Also, check the item before accessing any property, i.e: `if ($someItem)` and so on.

Comment: Please note that iteration over an object - like it's done in the **question** - does not work (in this case).

Comment: I cannot do this, as I need to go through the loops step by step. Is there a way I would iterate as mentioned in the question ?

Comment: @maan81, for a separate loop. you may try `$lis = $html->find('li'); foreach($lis as $li)`.